# Convex combination of positive mean-ergodic operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, banach-lattices

Let $T_1,T_2:L^1([0,1],\mathrm{d}x)\to L^1([0,1],\mathrm{d}x)$ be positive mean-ergodic operators such that:

- For every $h:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}_+$ we have that
  $$\int_0^1 T_1 h(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 T_2 h(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 h(x)\mathrm{d}x. $$
- $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Fix}(T_1))= \mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Fix}(T_2)=1$.
- $T_1^*,T_2^*:L^\infty([0,1],\mathrm{d}x)\to L^\infty([0,1],\mathrm{d}x)$, given $g\in L^\infty$, such that $T_1^*g=g$ or $ T_2^* g=g$ then $g$ is constant almost surely.
- Given $f_i\in \mathrm{Fix}(T_i)$ with $i=1,2$. We have that $f_i>0$ Lebesgue-a.s..

Under the above conditions, is possible to prove that for every $\lambda \in [0,1]$ the operator $S_\lambda := \lambda T_1 + (1-\lambda)T_2$ is mean-ergodic? I am interested in the case that $T_1$ and $T_2$ do not commute.

Any reference, counter-example or proof would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "mean-ergodic"?

Comment: @RW: I think this refers to the following notion: A bounded linear operator $T$ on a Banach space is called *mean ergodic* if the Cesàro means $1/n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T^k$ of the powers converge with respect to the strong (equivalently: weak) operator toplogy as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: The operator $T:L^1\to L^1$ is mean ergodic if there exists a projection operator $P:L^1\to L^1$ such that for every $f \in L^1$, we have that $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} T^i f\to Pf,$$in $L^1$.